# Highlighting Highcharts column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a column graph in highcharts and I want to be about to click on a single column and it stay highlighted until I click it again.

This will make the column highlight but I still need the background to do the same:

```
this.chart.series[0].data[0].setState('hover')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
           allowPointSelect:true,                
        }
    }
```

It will do the desired.

Demo [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/CkkbF/375/)